# How to run biztalk orchestration every X minutes

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2009, orchestration

I have an orchestration that is started by a public port published as service. Everytime somebody calls this service the orchestration starts

I need to start the orchestration every 30 minutes too.

Whats is the better approach? 
I've seen some [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michaelstephenson/archive/2008/05/16/122203.aspx) but I would like something more simple

Comment: The scheduled task adapter is easy to get up and running. http://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the blog post you referenced states, BizTalk doesn't really do scheduling.  Besides the approaches referenced in that post, I don't think there is really an easier approach to this problem.  You mention your orchestration is published as a service.  Could you create a simple command line application that calls your service and run that via Windows Schedule or SQLAgent?

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason it does not do things every X minutes. It would be a wrong usage of BizTalk. BizTalk is publish and subscribe. The repetitive process is for WIndows Services and if they need processing then, send to BizTalk from Windows Server.

When you do not publish, you do not receive.

This behaviour can be achieved, however, by an orchestration subscribing to an inbound port (file for example) and then drop a file back at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Write a batch file with reference to windows sheduler