# Biztalk orchestration published as Web Service consumed by Schedule Task Adapter

Tags: wcf, web-services, biztalk, biztalk-2009

As I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184753/how-to-run-biztalk-orchestration-every-x-minutes/8185016#8185016), I have an orchestration that is started by a public port published as a web service. Everytime this service is called the orchestration starts

I need to start the orchestration every 30 minutes too.

I ended up using the [Scheduled Task Adapter](http://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/) to call my own port. I created a scheduled receive port that creates messages every given time, and a send port that with a filter, receives messages from the port and send them to the web service port

Orchestation starts correctly, but there is an error:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.
```

[After researching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696050/unable-to-call-one-way-peoplesoft-service-with-wcf-adapter-from-biztalk-2010), I found out that Biztalk doesn't like one-way web services (even if this  web-service was generated by "Biztalk Web Service Publishing Wizard")

I found solutions like a [WCF-proxy](http://www.pvle.be/2008/12/calling-one-way-wcf-service-with-biztalk-wcf-adapter-part-2/), but I was wondering if I could just configure the orchestration webservice to be two-way (in the wizard you can force it) and then call it the way i'm doing now. I'm trying but still receiving similar errors

Anyone had a similar issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Listen shape to the start of your Orchestration, you can then have 2 (or more) parallel Activating Receive shapes.

Connect the secondary Receive shape to a new one-way logical port (Specify-later)

Once deployed, hook your Scheduled Task Adapter up to the one-way port, so it receives the regularly scheduled message.

As always with BizTalk, there is more than one way to de-fur a feline, but this was the first to come to mind.